# update using sum

Tags: sql-server, update

I am trying to update the `totalNumber` column of the **AccountDetails** table to be the `SUM()` of the `totalNumber` column of the **Trans** table, where the `accountID` and the `assetID` columns match.

The is the query I tried using:

```
UPDATE demo.dbo.AccountDetails
SET totalNumber=(
        SELECT SUM(totalNumber) FROM demo.dbo.Trans
        WHERE AccountDetails.accountId = Trans.accountId and AccountDetails.assetId = Trans.assetId
        GROUP BY accountId 
       )
  WHERE(
        SELECT totalNumber FROM demo.dbo.Trans
        WHERE AccountDetails.accountId = Trans.accountId and AccountDetails.assetId = Trans.assetId
        GROUP BY accountId 
  )
```

Howevery, this gives me the error:

> ```
> The multi-part identifier "AccountDetails.accountId" could not be bound.
> ```

Please note the the `accountID` can have many `assetID` and all are different.

### accountDetail Table

```
id  totalNUmber   assetId   accountId 
2   30.0000       1020      789 
3   412.0000      1021      768 
4   159.0000      1020      768 
9   225.0000      1021      789
```

### Trans Table

```
id  accountid   totalNumber   assetid
5   768         8.000000      1020
6   768         4.000000      1021  
7   789         6.000000      1021  
8   768         -100.000000   1021  
9   768         -89.000000    1021  
10  768         -9.000000     1021
11  769         -7.000000     1020
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did this on notepad, so might have some syntax errors.

```
UPDATE AD
SET totalNumber = tr.totalNumber
FROM demo.dbo.AccountDetails AD
JOIN (SELECT accountId, assetId, SUM(totalNumber) AS totalNumber 
      FROM demo.dbo.Trans
      GROUP BY accountId, assetId
      ) tr ON tr.accountId = AD.accountId AND tr.assetId = AD.assetId
```